# How can i do "union" on multiple spark structured streaming dataframes?

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka-streams, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to make a `union` operation on multiple structured streaming dataframe, connected to kafka topics, in order to watermark them all at the same moment.

For instance:

```
df1=socket_streamer(spark,topic1)
df2=socket_streamer(spark,topic2)
```

where spark=sparksession **and** socket_streamer = spark.readstream

then i'll do:

```
Dataframe=df1.union(df2)
Dataframe=Dataframe.withWatermark("timestamp","5 minutes")
```

then I try to writeStream Dataframe.

The issue is: the `union`  displays only the first `df` to receive rows.

Do you have any idea, to get all my data received by the union or how can I apply a same watermark on multiple dataframes ?

Tank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does df1 and df2 have the same structure? Union function in spark resolves columns by position (not by name).

To union by name, use:

```
df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True)
```

(available from Spark 3.1.X)